# Combine r.js and UglifyJS parameters

Tags: requirejs, uglifyjs, r.js

I'm optimizing my requirejs project with r.js. In my JS code, I need to replace an alias with the version number. It works fine when my `build.js` file contains the following:

```
({
    appDir: "../",
    baseUrl: "scripts",
    mainConfigFile: 'project-config.js',
    dir: "../dist",
    uglify: {
        defines: {
            DEBUG: ['name', 'true'],
            VERSION: ['string', '1.2.3.4']
        }   
    }
})
```

I run it via:
`node r.js -o build.js`

However, I need the version number to be passed dynamically as I want to optimize it through some command line tool. I've read about the `--define SYMBOL[=VALUE]` option in the [UglifyJS documentation](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS), but couldn't make it to work together.

What should I change in the node command to pass a "define" parameter to UglifyJS? I want to override the VERSION definition from the build.js file (or simply remove it from the file).

Answer (score 1):

According to James Burke who's responsible for r.js, this feature isn't supported yet - command line arguments are currently possible only for non-array attributes, see [pull request 346](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/pull/346).

Answer (score 0):

The only one way to use Uglify in command line is using:

```
optimize=uglify2
```

My reference is [the source](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/cf9abe82/build/example.build.js#L109)

Comment: The OP is not asking how to select UglifyJS as the minifier, but *how to pass parameters to the UglifyJS at the command line.*